# MSSQL_CONNECT NOT FOUND - PHP and IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I just installed PHP5.4 on my Windows Server 2012 R2 server with IIS and MS SQL Server 2012 Express.  I created a blank website with PHP enabled and attempted to make a connection to the database which is also on the server.    The problem I am having is that when I try to load the webpage, I get a HTTP 500 error.  I check the log and find the error below for each refresh.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'sqlsrv_connect' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 14

However, it is supported, as stated in phpinfo().  The extension is also enabled in the php.ini file.  Is there a hidden step that I missed when I installed PHP, or is there post installation configuration that needs to be done?

**phpinfo() output:**

[image: phpinfo()]

**php.ini extension list:**

[image: php.ini]

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the requested php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "MAINSERVER\SQLEXPRESS";
$username = "website";
$password = "website";
echo "Connecting to database";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $username, $password);
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: It's puzzling that php complains about a **class** it can't find, as sqlsrv_connect is a function.  Can you show us the code that causes the error?

Comment: Posted the php code. There is no other code in the index.php file except for tags required by html.